# Wrap individual character in <span> on keyUp using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to wrap each character to wrapped in a `<span></span>` and desire output is `<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span>`.

I have tried following but its not helping.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aau75w9q/1/)**

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="text1" type="text" placeholder="type something...">

$(function() {
  $("#text1").keyup(function(event) {
    $(this).wrapInner( "<span class='test'></span>" )
  });
});
```

It outputs following; which is not what I required. Any help?

```
<span class="test">
<span class="test">
    <span class="test">
        <span class="test">ffdf</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: @ScanQR - Look ath the questions That's OP not required but output come like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution. There is tag `code` below the input div, for control what is content of the div:

```js
txt = $("#text1").html();
$("#out").text(txt);
$(function() {
    $("#text1").keyup(function(event) {
        txt = txt + "<span class='test'>"+String.fromCharCode(event.which)+"</span>";
        $(this).html(txt);
        $("#out").text($(this).html());
    });
});
```

```css
#text1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="text1" type="text" placeholder="type something..."></div>
<code id="out"></code>
```

Pure function of replacing char looks like:

```
txt = $("#text1").html();
$(function() {
    $("#text1").keyup(function(event) {
        txt += "<span>" + String.fromCharCode(event.which) + "</span>";
        $(this).html(txt);
    });
});
```

Here is another one where **case-sensitive** func `keypress` used along with `preventDefault()` to prevent a redundant character appear:

```js
txt = $("#text1").html();
$(function() {
    $("#text1").keypress(function(event) {
       txt += "<span>" + String.fromCharCode(event.which) + "</span>";
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).html(txt);
       $("#out").text(txt);
    });
});
```

```css
#text1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="text1" type="text" placeholder="type something..."></div>
<code id="out"></code>
```

Comment: nice one ,.  i am trying to do this until i saw this

Answer (score 1):

is this what you need ?

```js
$(function(){
$("#text1").keyup(function(event) {
$('.test').each(function (index) {
    var characters = $(this).text().split("");
    
    $this = $(this);
    $this.empty();
    $.each(characters, function (i, el) {
    $this.append("<span>" + el + "</span");
    });

});

});
});
```

```css
#text1 {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 24px;
    width: 127px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="text1" type="text" placeholder="type something..."></div>

<span class="test">ffdf</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about splitting your string first ?

```
$(function() {
  $("#text1").keyup(function(event) {
    $(this).text().split('').wrapInner( "<span class='test'></span>" )
  });
});
```

Comment: what you want try to say for the world?

Comment: $(this).html($(this).text().split('').wrapInner("<span class='test'></span>")) Quite a mouthful

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the content by `.split("")`

```js
var myText = $("#text").html();

var myTextArr = myText.split("");
$("#text").empty();

myTextArr.forEach(function(val, idx){
$("#text").append("<span class='test'>" + val + "</span>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='text'>ABC</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be try using `text()` and do `substr()` ti get last character entered recently and add the `<span>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text1").keyup(function(event) {

    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).wrapInner("<span class='test'>" + txt.substr(txt.length, txt.length - 1) + "</span>");
  });
});
```

```css
#text1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="text1" type="text" placeholder="type something...">
```

Comment: it outputs same as I did... my desired output is `<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span>`

Answer (score 1):

Since goal is to type/replace (simultaneously!), i have used this:

```js
arr=[];
$(function() {
$("#text1").keyup(function(event) {

clean=$( this )
  .contents()
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).text();
    
 
output="";
arr.push(clean.charAt(clean.length-1));

for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
output+="<span class='test'>"+arr[i]+"</span>";
}
$(this).html(output);

//console.log(output);
  });
});
```

```css
#text1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height:200px;
}
.test {
  background:pink;
  color:white;
  margin-left:3px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="text1" type="text" placeholder="type something..."></div>
```

So, first - filter just text inside div, and wrap it with desired html.

P.S. span CSS is here just for test purposes.

P.S. 2 Not sure about white spaces (and desired functionality) - but they can be removed, too...

Test without span CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/aau75w9q/4/ (produced HTML is what is required, if i understand correctly)