# input keypress function - something wrong

Tags: jquery, html

I want show an alert if user press Enter key in a text input, but something is wrong:

```
<input type='text' id='inputrename' placeholder='type and press Enter'>
```

**js**

```
$('#inputrename').keypress(function(event) {
if (event.keycode === 13) {
    alert ('323');
}
});
```

Alert does not appear.

```js
$('#inputrename').keypress(function(event) {
if (event.keycode === 13) {
 alert ('323');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='mdinput' id='inputrename' maxlength='50' placeholder='type and press Enter'>
```

Comment: Try `keyCode`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41261180/4206079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `keyCode` instead of `keycode`

```js
$('#inputrename').keypress(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
 alert ('323');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='mdinput' id='inputrename' maxlength='50' placeholder='type and press Enter'>
```

Comment: Thansk a lot. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $( function(){
    
    $( '#inputrename' ).keydown( function(e){
      
      if( e.which  === 13 )
        alert( 'Enter key pressed' )
      
    } );
    
  } );
</script>

<input type='text' class='mdinput' id='inputrename' maxlength='50' placeholder='type and press Enter'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#inputrename').keypress(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.charCode === 13 ) {
 alert ('323');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='mdinput' id='inputrename' maxlength='50' placeholder='type and press Enter'>
```

[**event.keyCode:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.keyCode) Returns the Unicode value of a non-character key in a keypress event or any key in any other type of keyboard event.

[**event.charCode:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode) Returns the Unicode value of a character key pressed during a keypress event.